# render using a custom json method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord

One of my active record subclasses has a method that creates a json-like representation.  Is this the way to answer an array of that data?

```
# answer is an array
answer = MyModel.fetch()

respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => answer.collect { |e| e.as_special_json } }
end
```

I don't think this is right.  I guess I don't really understand what render :json is all about.  I think this will json encode the almost-json.  Is there any way to just answer the almost-json like any other json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just render it as text:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.special_json { render :text => answer.collect{ |e| e.as_special_json } }
end
```

Your can access add a `.special_json` to your url to make rails render the text. You need to map the new mime symbol "special_json" to the json mime type. Just add this line to `config/initializers/mime_types.rb`:

```
Mime::Type.register "application/json", :special_json
```